# psycopg2 select result gets nested with additional array

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to get JSON rows from postgres using "psycopg2".  value of records is like [ [{....},{...},{...}] ].  To get the correct JSON result ie. [{....},{...},{...}] i have to go for records1.  Not sure why this is happening.

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import json

conn_string = "'host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='postgres' password='password123'" 
con=psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select json_agg(art) from (select a.*, (select json_agg(b) from (select * from pfstklist where pfportfolioid = a.pfportfolioid ) as b) as pfstklist, (select json_agg(c) from (select * from pfmflist where pfportfolioid = a.pfportfolioid ) as c) as pfmflist from pfmaindetail as a) art")
records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)     #This gives result [[{....},{...},{...}]]
records1=records[0]    
print(records1)   #This gives expected result [{....},{...},{...}]
```

Comment: is it python?!! tag the language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`cur.fetchall()` gives you a list of records. You probably want `cur.fetchone()`.